# Is it possible to create a function ( in C ), that can operate with different structure?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, unions

i'm looking for creating a function in C language that allows me to receive different structures type as parameters.
For example, if I create 3 different structures

```
struct a{
    struct datatype0{
         char test1[10];
    }datatype;
    struct a *next;
};

struct b{
    struct datatype1{
        int test1;
        char test2[20];
        int test3;
    }datatype;
    struct b *next;
};

struct c{
    struct datatype2{
        char test1;
        char test2;
        float test3;
        int test4;
        int test5;
    }datatype;
    struct c *next;
};
```

I wanna create a function that can receives one of theese three different struct as parameter, so I can call only it for initialize first, or second or third kind of structure:

```
void function("---")//<-- inside the brackets i need to insert a parameter that can be struct a, or struct b or struct c.
{
//here for example I can insert the initialize function that have to work with any struct.

}
```

I tryed to use a union, but I saw that I have to recreate the initializing function for each kind of struct...I tryed to use void pointers, but i need to cast theese inside the function and I need to create initializing function for each kind of struct too...
Any ideas??

Comment: Which C? In  C11,  _Generic will let you do this. In C89 or C99 you have to build the dispatch machinery yourself

Comment: It's rarely a good practice to do that.

Comment: Yeah, don't use _Generic, probably.    You're on the right path with unions.  Can you explain what you mean by "have to recreate the initializing function for each kind of struct"?

Comment: Wait wait wait! BadZen U r good! You gave me an idea! wait a second that i test it!

Comment: @BadZen "don't use _Generic" deserves explanation as `_Generic` is certainly a candidate solution.

Comment: @chux  -  C11 is still fairly poorly supported on a lot of compilers.   I'd consider code that uses it to not be highly portable.   It's also not something that most devs are familiar with yet.

Answer (score 1):

The long and short of it is: avoid to do this whenever possible, but know that you *Can* pass different structs to a single function if you really have to.

Probably the easiest way is to create a wrapper struct, that contains 2 members: a union, and a flag to let you know which struct is passed.

```
typedef enum {
    A,
    B,
    C
} struct_type;

struct _wrapper {
    union {
        struct a A;
        struct b B;
        struct c C;
    };
    struct_type flag;
};

void my_function(struct _wrapper *data)
{
    switch (data->flag)
    {
        case A:
            struct a val = data.A;
            //do stuff with A
            break;
        case B:
            struct b val = data.B;
            break;
        case C:
            struct c val = data.C;
            //...
            break;
    }
}
```

Another option, although it's considered bad practice, and is something you'll end up regretting is to rely on the fact that the offset of the first member of any struct is guaranteed to be 0. You can cast a pointer to any struct to a pointer to its first member. If the first member of all structs is compatible, you can rely on that (***at your own risk***).
One way of exploiting this is to set a function pointer as first member, or an enum field that you can use as a flag to identify the struct:

```
struct a {
    void (*common_member)();//
    /** other members **/
};
struct b {
    void (*common_member)();//needn't be the same name though
    /** other members **/
};
```

Then:

```
void my_func(void *data)
{//void pointer
    ((void (*)(void *))data)(data);//cast void *data to function pointer, and pass itself as an argument
}
```

This can work, if the structs are properly initialized, and the members point to the correct functions, but that's too many if's to rely on really.

Using the enum as first member is slightly less risky, but still not to be recommended. It's a sort of a combination of the function pointer and union approach

```
void my_func(void *data)
{
    //cast void * to struct_type *, dereference AFTER the cast
    //because you can't dereference a void *
    switch(*((struct_type *) data))
    {
        case A: /* stuff */ break;
        case B: /* struct b */ break;
    }
}
```

All in all, use the first approach. Do not use the function pointer members, and acknowledge the third approach for what it is: true, you don't need a wrapper struct, but it's not that much safer than the original approach (function pointers), and no less verbose than the first approach (with union).

Bottom line: structs and unions are the way to go

Answer (score 0):

In part it works. But for example, if I wanna create a function like:

```
typedef union elemento{
    struct a A;
    struct b B;
    struct c C;
}elemento;

void inserimentoOrdinato(elemento dausare){
    struct b prova;
    prova.datatype.test1 = 3;
    strcpy(prova.datatype.test2,"TESTA");
    prova.datatype.test3 = 200;
    prova.next = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a));
    dausare.B = prova;
}
```

I need to use "dausare.B" or "dausare.C" for the different kinds of structures. It doesn't know itseflt which part of union has to use. Am I rigth? Thank you!

Comment: Note: consider allocating by the variable's referenced type rather than allocating by type (which might not match the variable's pointer), `prova.next = malloc(sizeof *prova.next);`  Also cast not needed.

Comment: BTW: This code fails to initialize the calling code's `elemento`.  `dausare` is a copy of the calling code's `elemento`, so any changes to `dausare` will not be seen after the function completes.  I would expect something like `void inserimentoOrdinato(elemento *dausare, int type) {`

Comment: It was only a test, I know that out of the function there are no changes!:) And I think that I found a solution. If it will work, i will post it here.

Comment: @GiorgioNocera: `prova.next = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a));` <-- don't cast the return of `malloc`. The best way to allocate memory is to write something like `var.member = malloc(sizeof *var.member);`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is generic programming and function pointer:

**void * can be a pointer to any struct

Declaration part:

```
typedef void *Initializer(void* obj);//since every struct has its own fields to initialize

void function(void * obj, Initializer init)
{
    init(obj);
}
```

Usage:

```
void InitA(void* a_void)
{
    struct a* a  = (struct a*) a_void;
    //init a feilds
    a->next = NULL;
}

void InitB(void* b_void)
{
    struct b* b  = (struct b*) b_void;
    //init b feilds
    b->next = NULL;
}

void InitC(void* c_void)
{
    struct c* c  = (struct c*) c_void;
    //init a feilds
    c->next = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    struct a a;
    struct b b;
    struct c c;

    Init(&a,InitA);
    Init(&b,InitB);
    Init(&c, initC);

    return 0;
}
```

***Keep in mind that you dont have to build a different function for each struct if they have the same fields to initialize.